# addClass & removeClass to many divs - is there a smarter way than this?

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I'm writing a page that has a list of links, and a list of logos. When I hover over a link (#chicken_link) that matches the corresponding logo or logos (.chicken_shops) the .chicken_shops div gets a class of 'active' applied to it so I can do some css-ing with it.

I have the functionality I was after, but I think there has to be a smarter way to write this than how I've done it.  If it's not obvious, I am not very well versed in js.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chicken_link').hover(
        function(){$('.chicken_shops').addClass('active');},
        function(){$('.chicken_shops').removeClass('active');}
    );

    $('#rice_link').hover(
        function(){$('.rice_shops').addClass('active');},
        function(){$('.rice_shops').removeClass('active');}
    );

    $('#beans_link').hover(
        function(){$('.beans_shops').addClass('active');},
        function(){$('.beans_shops').removeClass('active');}
    );
    <!-- etc. -->
});
</script>
```

My html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="chicken_link">Chicken</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="rice_link">Rice</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="beans_link">Beans</a></li>
    <!-- etc. -->
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="chicken_shops"><a href="#">The Chicken Shop</a></li>
    <li class="rice_shops"><a href="#">The Rice Shop</a></li>
    <li class="beans_shops">The Bean Shop</li>
    <!-- etc. -->
</ul>
```

It works, but how can I write this in a more compact or smarter way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* wanted to stick to Javascript, you might consider using less specific selectors instead.

For instance, using a class selector would be an good solution in that it ensures that you target everything you want but nothing more. You could also save some markup and use `ul li` if every unordered list on your site will have this behavior.

Here are two solutions. Click the titles to see examples.

## [Javascript solution, using classes](http://jsfiddle.net/AVUzg/1)

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.toggle').hover(
    function(){ $(this).addClass('active'); },
    function(){ $(this).removeClass('active'); }
  );

});
```

#### Html

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="chicken_link" class="toggle">Chicken</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="rice_link" class="toggle">Rice</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="beans_link" class="toggle">Beans</a></li>
</ul>
```

## [Css solution, using :hover](http://jsfiddle.net/FjDLq/)

Depending on how much functionality you're adding to this thing, I'd personally prefer to just use the `:hover` pseudoclass and skip out on the Javascript altogether.

#### Css

```
.toggle:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @jmeas but what I actually need to do is hover on chicken_link and make the li with chicken_shop get the active class, so I think that $(this) won't work for me (hehe). This is what I need to do - but can I do it with less code?  http://jsfiddle.net/MaryL/CzZGZ/1/